# Simulate borders with CSS

Tags: css, border, html-table

When I add td element with a dark background in my table that has a light background with a border, I want that in the dark td element, the border of the table doesn't see.

For example:

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 40%;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    padding: 10px;
}

td.black {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="black">Something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Something else</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the first td, the dark td, I don't want to see the yellow border of the table.

Comment: So, remove the borders, or change border-color, for cells in the `.black` element class?

Comment: I want the border of the table, but a custom one for the dark td element, in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/arc2jg49/ (but in this way I use div element). If I add a border-color for the black element class, the border of the table remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, but you could just add the border to the default 'td' element insted of 'table' and create a special rule for the black one.

```
table {
width: 40%;
border-spacing: 0;
/* border-collapse: collapse; // get a single border */
}

td {
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid yellow;
 }

td.black {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
border: 2px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pr1d3c5b/

If you want to add just a box-shadow, you can try with this variation (for red color), but it's not precise

```
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pr1d3c5b/1/

You can try this generator http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/ and play with the 'spread' value under the optional settings

Comment: With box-shadow? Can I do anything? Or outline?